# PHP: class inheritance - best practice

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I'm aware there's `extends` for class inheritance but i'm requiring a different approach:

I want to achieve the following class structure:

```
c_main
|
--- c_subclass1
|
--- c_subclass2
|
--- c_subclass3
```

the idea:
`c_main` holds functionality for all classes, like scraping, status messages, database- and error handling, logging ..
so the child classes always need to have access to the main class.

in detail:
subclass1 will load the main id for all subclasses, therefore the subclasses need to communicate between each other - like:
subclass1 will get the id - subclass2 will do extensive scraping based on it and collect data and pass something to subclass 3 which will also collect data.
all subclasses need to access the parent class, as it will write an ongoing logfile of the process which is going on between the subclasses.
in the end, c_main will contain the final data from all subclasses.

my current approach is as follows

```
class c_main
{
    public $id;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->sub1 = new c_subclass1(this);
        $this->sub2 = new c_subclass2(this);
        $this->sub3 = new c_subclass3(this);
    }

    function log($msg, $obj)
    {
        $class = get_class($obj);
        $msg = "class: " . $class . " | " . $msg;
        // write $msg to consistent log 
    }

    function scrape($url, $obj)
    {
        $this->log("scraping: $url", $obj);
    }

    function load()
    {
        $this->id = $this->sub1->get_id();
        $data2 = $this->sub2->get_data();
        $data3 = $this->sub3->get_data();

        $this->all = array( $data1, $data2, $data3 );
    }

}
```

`subclass1` would look like this:

```
class c_subclass1
{
    function __construct( $oMain )
    {
        $this->oMain = $oMain;
    }

    function get_id()
    {
        $this->oMain->log("getting id  ..", $this);
        $id = $this->oMain->scrape("www.foo.com", $this);
        return $id;
    }

}
```

`subclass2` would look like this:

```
class c_subclass2
{
    function __construct( $oMain )
    {
        $this->oMain = $oMain;
    }

    function get_data()
    {
        $this->oMain->log("getting data for id " . $this->id . " ..", $this);
        $aData = $this->oMain->scrape("www.bar.com?id=" . $this->id, $this);
        return $aData;
    }

}
```

i'm wondering: is this the best method or is there a better way?

Comment: just define the classes like `c_themoviedb extends c_movie` and define the properties and methods of `c_movie` as `protected` so the children can access them.

Comment: Why are you creating object of child classes in parent class then?

Comment: Why not just use extends? It's exactly what you need.....

Comment: i know it sounds strange, but i also want the child classes being able to communicate with each other during parsing so i always need to have access to the c_movie object

Comment: It seems like your question is about composition vs inheritance. Though I'm wondering why exactly do the c_themoviedb and others need to know about the movie?

Comment: it's a bit hard to explain, simplified: subclass1 will scrape something which is required by subclass2 and if anything is finished, c_movie will contain the full data - so i need to "push" the subclass data to the parent object

Comment: @Fuxi, update your question with the above comment?

Comment: ok i updated my question in detail ;)

Comment: It sounds horrible to have classes that use files, database accesses, arrays mixed with all different data - and all that within only a little number of classes

Comment: For a start, please also read the PHP PSR guidelines. `c_subclass1` is not a generally accepted class name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to inherit multiple classes but php not allowing more than 1 inheritance and php provides [Traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) mechanism, Read php documents that will help you to find best way.

> A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single inheritance

Comment: Maybe share your implementation of `Traits` instead of only definition? Anway, I think this is a good use case for OP's question.